# Clarification on Browser Event Handling Mechanism

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener

I'm seeking clarification on how event handling works in web browsers. This is what I thought happens:
When we use function like `addEventListener(<some event>, <some handler>)`, we are telling the browser to now start listening for this event on this DOM node on a separate thread and when the event triggers, to then call the specified handler. If this is the case, when this function is called multiple times for the same event on the same DOM node, does this create multiple listener threads or is the same listener thread updated for the list of handlers to call?

But then I came across event propagation and I read that even if no listeners were added, the propagation mechanism still runs, it just doesn't find any handlers and thus nothing happens. This would mean that some code is still there which is listening. So my above understanding is wrong.

Is it the case that when we load a webpage, the browser starts listening to events from that point only. When we are calling functions like `addEventListener`, we are just registering the handlers. Hence even if this function was not called even once, the propagation chain will still run because something was listening to events. If this is correct then why is the function called `addEventListener`. Its a bit misleading. Shouldn't it be called something like `addHandler` or `registerHandler`.

Comment: The browser is always listening for events; you are listening for the browser's abstractions over the OS events.

Answer (score 0):

Your comprehension of event handling in web browsers is accurate.The term "addEventListener" may seem misleading, as it implies the addition of an "event listener thread," whereas the function actually registers an event handler function. This nomenclature is historical and signifies the act of adding a function to be executed upon a specific event. Although names like addHandler or registerHandler might convey the purpose more explicitly, the established convention and compatibility with the existing codebase are often prioritized.
your recognition that browsers commence event listening upon webpage load is accurate. The addEventListener function essentially registers handlers for execution when specific events occur, without generating additional threads for each handler. Its primary function is to associate functions with events on DOM nodes. Despite the imperfect naming convention, it has become a standard term in web development.

Let me add further details on some key points:

1. When you employ **addEventListener**, you are essentially enrolling an event handler function for a specific event on a DOM node. Browser events are typically processed asynchronously, often managed by an event loop in the main thread. It's crucial to clarify that the term "thread" may not precisely characterize this process, as events are usually processed in the main thread, and the associated handlers are queued for execution.
2. If you **call addEventListener multiple times** for the same event on a particular DOM node, it doesn't create multiple threads. Instead, it adds multiple handlers for that event on the specified node. When the event occurs, all registered handlers are called in the order in which they were added.
3. **Event propagation** consists of three phases: capturing, target, and bubbling. Even in the absence of added listeners, propagation still occurs. This mechanism enables events to traverse the DOM hierarchy—from the root to the target element and then back up. If no listeners are added, event propagation concludes without invoking any handlers.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying `addEventListener` is a bad name or why it would imply that a new thread is created. The OP just needs to understand the event loop that is always checking for events and finding their listeners to call.